# can't connect to server after installing let's encrypt on centos 8

Tags: apache-http-server, centos, ssl, letsencrypt, certbot

I'm trying to install `let's encrypt` on my centos 8 apache server. I created `domain-site.conf` file in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/` directory with the following content (domain name is replaced with test):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@test.com
DocumentRoot "/home"
ServerName test.com
ServerAlias www.test.com
ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/test.error_log"
CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/test.access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

and then installed certbot to get an SSL certificate and also redirect http requests to https requests. certbot gives a congratulations message at the end but when I try to access my server using a browser, it says "This site can’t be reached".

this problem happened after installing lets encrypt. how to figure out what is the problem?!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your SSL (HTTPS) virtual host configuration file(s).

Answer (score 1):

There is probably something messed up with the redirection to HTTPS.
Have you let certbot configure redirection himself, during the guided installation?
This virtualhost file you shared is configured for port 80 and not 443 and there is no reference to the `mod_ssl` module.
Can you check your Apache folder for other virtualhosts files?
Do you get redirected to HTTPS when you reach your website at all?

Comment: thanks for your response. the problem was the https service was not added to firewall public: `firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=https` it solved the issue

Comment: Nice, it was something fairly simple in fact; but without any mention to the ports and firewall configuration I didn't thought about it